# Load Audio and Images quietly

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, create-react-app, preload

I am using create-react-app and have  approx lets call the assets as follows..
1000x Image
1000x svgs

Only a subset is loaded on different screens and none on the home page.
E.g. on page 1, 50 images and 50 svg 
.. page 2 ... 75 images and 75 svg... and so on..

I was wondering is there a way that after the home page loads.. componentDidMount..

I could start preloading the page 1 ones assets and then page 2 etc async whatever would be a good practice?

Note, I intend enabled PWA. So, should I save assets to localStorage or will that be handled by service worker already and thay my preloader idea simply needs to do its thing?

What I want to achieve is
1. PWA that fetches all assests on install
2. Preload all assets in background async

I am junior dev so any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will start loading your images once it hits an `<img />` tag.

You can render your images first but hide them using `display: none;`.

The create-react-app uses `cache-first` strategy, which means every image you import will be cached in the browser's cache storage.